# Are multiple return values in PHP -- accepted / good practice?

Tags: php

in other languages it's common practice to have multiple return values. in Lua for example one could write:

```
local _, _, r1, r2 = string.find(...)
```

(the `_` is in lua common practice for "throw-away" return values)

in PHP i would have to write something like:

```
list(, , $r1, $r2) = string_find(...);
```

While you can see the usage of multiple return values in Lua really almost everywhere (in almost every program), i've seen this in PHP not very often -- besides of the `while(list(...) = each(...)) { }` case.

What is your opinion about multiple return values especially in PHP -- good practice or bad code?

thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by multiple return values - do you mean returning an array?

Comment: @xil3: no, it's not an array, nor an object, but something very different. And it's only available in some languages: in C#, for example, you can return tuples, but a tuple is just an ordinary object. Returning multiple values would be something like: `(firstName, lastName) = this.GetPersonName();`.

Comment: PHP has less of a nice syntax for it, but it's as acceptable as in other languages (if used in moderation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in using multiple return values in PHP. At least if you are using it well. There are some situations when it can really help (for example returning a tuple can by funny doing this way).

Of course, you must be careful when documenting such methods. Also, if you are returning twenty values from a method, there is something very wrong with it. But, again, it's not related to PHP.

Now, why it's not used very often in PHP? In my opinion, because most people writing PHP programs are unaware of that.

Comment: thanks. i like your answer a lot, especially the last part about the unawareness of this feature. the documentation is indeed a problem. how would you do it?

Comment: You can leave it simpel and just also use DocBlocks for this: `$return array 2-tupel with (name : string, age : string)`. Its up to you, how you write it down, but its not difficult to document in a way everybody understand.

Comment: In all cases, there is no official way to document things to get intellisense in PHP, like you do in C#. So when writing documentation for multiple return values, do it as you do for single-return-value methods, thus precising what are the parts of multiple return values.

Answer (score 2):

It's more common in PHP to return an array or an object, then work with that array or object directly, rather than assign all the values to separate variables.

```
function get_preferences() {
    return array('color' => 'red', 'size' => 'large', 'material' => 'cotton');
}

$prefs = get_preferences();

echo "We're sending you a " . $prefs['size'] . " shirt.";
```

Comment: yes, i know ... i used objects and hashes as return values myself before, but i liked the lua way very much and i wondered, why it's not common practice in php, too. i think @MainMa is right, that a lot of php programmers are unaware of this and this might be the case, that it's not widely adopted.

Answer (score 2):

To make that clear: "Return an array" is not the same as "return multiple values". Later one is simply not possible.

I sometimes return an array as a kind of "tupel", but there are very rare cases, where this is required. In most cases a function/method will return specific value.

For example you need a function, that splits a string at a given index. In this case I would return an array

```
function my_split ($string, $index) {
  return array(
    substr($string,0, $index),
    substr($string,$index)
  );
}
list($start, $end) = my_split("Hello World", 5);
```

Comment: i see. so you use it, whereever it's useful / makes sense and you don't have bad feelings about it ... ?

Comment: No, should I? Its just a tupel and tupels are well-defined datatypes. So why should php developers not use this types? And as I mentioned: There are really not much cases, that requires tupels to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

I consider it to be okay, if used reasonably. Your second example, the one with `while(list(...) = each(...))`, is an example of where not to use it. Here it is just a slower variant of a `foreach` loop.

PS: Something I found recently: One can nest `list()s` :)

Comment: i did not know of this nested list thing, but if you think a little bit about it, there's no reason, why it should not work. thanks for sharing :). do you actually use it?

Comment: @harald: No, never used it before. But while browsing in PHP's y-file I always find curiosities like nested `list`s or by-ref lambdas (`function&(){}`). Just wanted to point out ;)